# ^x^y unix trick for all instances in last command?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, command-history

One of my favorite Unix tricks is `^x^y`, which will take the last command and replace the first instance of "x" with "y". However, I'm wondering if a similar trick works to replace *all* instances of "x" with "y" in the last command?

Comment: The feature is called history expansion.  Looks like we use the `command-history` tag for that.  Added.  Also, I assume you're referring to the `bash` shell?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can use the `!!:gs/search/replace/` notation to do what you want. This utilizes the global search & replace (`:gs`):

*before*

```
$ echo "harm warm swarm barm"
harm warm swarm barm
```

*after*

```
$ !!:gs/arm/orn/
echo "horn worn sworn born"
horn worn sworn born
```

#### References

- [The Definitive Guide to Bash Command Line History](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/)
- [Caret search and replace in Bash shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149482/caret-search-and-replace-in-bash-shell)

Comment: @slm this command is replacing just the first instance for me . `[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ echo "hat that bat"
hat that bat
[subhrcho@slc04lyo pcbpel]$ !!:gs/at/xx/
echo "hxx that bat"
hxx that bat`.  What am I missing?

Comment: @Geek - what's your distro? Are you using Bash? Version? `bash --version` = 4.2.45(1)-release.

Comment: @slm GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: @Geek - too old a version, doesn't offer this feature.

Answer (score 65):

I don't believe there's an easy way to add something to `^string1^string2` to make `bash` replace every occurrence.  As slm points out, you have to write `!!:gs/string1/string1`.

But in `zsh`, you can just add `:G`:

```
$ echo foo foo
foo foo
$ ^foo^bar^:G
echo bar bar
bar bar
```

In both `bash` and `zsh`, you can also use `fc -s` like this:

```
$ echo foo foo
foo foo
$ fc -s foo=bar
echo bar bar
bar bar
```

This is often made into an alias called `r` so you can just do:

```
$ echo foo foo
foo foo
$ r foo=bar
echo bar bar
bar bar
```

Comment: Wow, this is really neat too

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the best option is to use ":&"

```
$ echo "dog cat dog"
$ ^dog^cat^:&
echo "cat cat cat"
cat cat cat
```

But like  Stéphane Chazelas commented below, this replaces just 2 occurrences. If you have more, you'd need to add more :&

Comment: That replaces **2** occurrences, not *all* of them (well all in this example as there are only 2 occurrence, but not in the general case). You'd need to add as many `:&` as there are more occurrences to replace.

Comment: What is the `:&` operator? :thinking: