# How can I replace a string in a previous command on the command-line?

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to run a command, and then run the same command again with just one string changed.

For example, I run the command

```
$ ./myscript.sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/code -c code1 -t query
```

Now from there, without going back in the command history (via the up arrow), I need to replace `code1` with `mycode` or some other string.

Can it be done in Bash?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: may the url contain other `b` ?

Comment: Can you please clarify how you get the initial string in input. From your post it seems it is on your terminal likewise you typed it as a command

Comment: Raja... a variation of  `echo http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/a/b/b/c/d/e | sed 's/b/c/g'`? Please tell what do you want to do, execute a command,call a program that will reach that url, change a variable value...?!?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116623/xy-unix-trick-for-all-instances-in-last-command for `fc-s`.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I renamed your script, but here's an option:

```
$ ./myscript.sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/code -c code1 -t query
```

after executing the script, use:

```
$ ^code1^code2
```

... which results in:

```
./myscript.sh xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/code -c code2 -t query
```

`man bash` and search for "Event Designators":

> ^string1^string2^
>
> Quick substitution.  Repeat the last command, replacing string1 with string2.   Equivalent to !!:s/string1/string2/

Editing to add global replacement, which I learned just now from @slm's answer at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116626/117549:

```
$ !!:gs/string1/string2
```

which says:

```
!! - recall the last command
g - perform the substitution over the whole line
s/string1/string2 - replace string1 with string2
```

Comment: Of course you use `!!` to repeat the previous command in its entirety, unaltered, but almost anything that begins with `!!:` can be shortened to `!:`; e.g., `!:gs/string1/string2`.

Comment: The `^` syntax works in `zsh` as well. Just documenting for posterity.

Comment: `^foo^bar^:G` for global search and replace.

Comment: @HappyFace *"`^foo^bar^:G` for global search and replace."* Doesn't work for me in Bash 4.4.19. Is that a `zsh` syntax?

Comment: @wisbucky Yeah, it's zsh.

Answer (score 6):

The bash builtin command `fc` can be used to find a command in the history and optionally edit/run it. Use the bash builtin `help fc` for more documentation.

```
fc -s code1=code2
```

Will find the all occurrences of code1 in the last command and change it to code2, then execute the new command.

It can be useful when multiple special characters need to be changed.
Suppose the previous command was;

```
$ java a/b/c/d

# Then,

fc -s /=.

# will produce
$ java a.b.c.d
```

Comment: Sometimes taking a little bit more time to add an explanation and where to find further information, will change an difficult answer to understand into something easier to read/understand and adds value to the set of answers.