# How to execute shell command produced using echo and sed?

Tags: bash, sed, command

I have tried doing:

```
echo " mv /server/today/logfile1 /nfs/logs/ && gzip /nfs/logs/logfile1" | sed 's|logfile1|logfile2|g'
```

It printed:

```
mv /server/today/logfile2 /nfs/logs/ && gzip /nfs/logs/logfile2
```

which is a bash command. How can I make it get executed, instead of
just printing it?

Comment: I tried to answer your question as formulated, but it's not obvious to me how this is useful; are you actually trying to accomplish something more complicated?

Comment: @dhag  and upvoter Yes it will help me to move log files with out using side keys.

Comment: @dhag my initial question is http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243317/bash-how-can-i-replace-a-string-in-a-previous-command but at comment given for answer I have mentioned my problem. I am trying to solve it but stuck here.... If you still want more information why I need to get this.

Comment: Is your actual problem that you have a bunch of files within `/server/today/`, and that you would like to move and gzip all of them? If so, I will suggest a simpler / safer solution.

Comment: @dhag please go on

Comment: You'll get better answers when you tell _why_ you're trying to do something, and you're desired _end result_.  There are many valid answers to your question that won't help you achieve you goal.  Explaining the context of the problem helps get better answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could pipe your command into a shell so it gets executed:

```
echo "mv ..." | bash
```

Or you could pass it as an argument to a shell:

```
bash -c "$(echo "mv ...")"
```

Or you could use the bash built-in `eval`:

```
eval "$(echo "mv ...")"
```

Note, however, that all of those code-generating commands look a bit brittle to me (there are ways they will fail as soon as some of the paths contain spaces, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You're reimplementing history substitution.

```
$ mv /server/today/logfile1 /nfs/logs/ && gzip /nfs/logs/logfile1
$ !!:gs/logfile1/logfile2
```

If you haven't actually executed the first command yet, and just want to execute a set of similar commands, consider a loop:

```
for f in logfile logfile2; do
    mv /server/today/"$f" /nfs/logs && gzip /nfs/logs/"$f"
done
```

Comment: I have similar script that does same as  your 2nd script do but the 1st one is impressive .  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done with `xargs`:

```bash
echo "mv ..." | sed "..." | xargs command
```

Examples:

```bash
$ echo "whoareyou" | sed "s/areyou/ami/g" | xargs command

username
```

- If there are `&&` or similar, you also need `eval`:

```bash
$ echo "whoareyou && whoareyou" | sed "s/areyou/ami/g" | xargs command eval

username
username
```

To also print what command is executed:

- `xargs -t`

```bash
$ echo "whoareyou && whoareyou" | sed "s/areyou/ami/g" | xargs -t command eval

command eval whoami '&&' whoami
username
username
```

- `tee`

```bash
echo "whoareyou && whoareyou" | sed "s/areyou/ami/g" | tee >(sh)

whoami && whoami
username
username
```

Comment: Note that OP's example won't work with xargs, since xargs doesn't understand `&&`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! It should work correctly in those cases with `xargs command eval`.