# What does the combination ^foo^bar do in Bash?

Tags: bash

I recently saw a video where someone executed `^foo^bar` in Bash. What is that combination for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [^x^y unix trick for all instances in last command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116623/xy-unix-trick-for-all-instances-in-last-command) and [related](https://www.google.fr/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149482/caret-search-and-replace-in-bash-shell&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwitu4nh4JXYAhXEaFAKHYE1CR8QFggLMAA&usg=AOvVaw1-gSC9hIEU5KIa1bujCNSl)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Bash calls this a **quick substitution**. It's in the "History Expansion" section of the Bash man page, under the "Event Designators" section ([online manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Event-Designators.html#Event-Designators)):

> `^string1^string2^`
>
> Quick substitution.  Repeat the previous command, replacing string1 with string2.  Equivalent  to  `!!:s/string1/string2/`

So `^foo^bar` would run the previously executed command, but replace the first occurence of `foo` with `bar`.

Note that for `s/old/new/`, the bash man page says "The  final
              delimiter  is  optional  if  it  is the last character of the
              event line."  This is why you can use `^foo^bar` and aren't required to use `^foo^bar^`.

<sub>(See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-your-favorite-command-line-features-or-tricks/67#67) for a bunch of other designators, although I didn't mention this one there).</sub>

Comment: Really nice. Didn't know this exists.

Answer (score 15):

`^foo^bar` executes that last command, replacing the first instance of `foo` with `bar`. For example:

```
$ ech "hello"
-bash: ech: command not found
$ ^ech^echo
echo "hello"
hello
```